# Reduce two rows into a single row in R

Tags: r

I have a situation such like this:

```
df<-data.frame(A=c(1, NA), B=c(NA, 2), C=c(3, NA), D=c(4, NA), E=c(NA, 5))
df
   A  B  C  D  E
1  1 NA  3  4 NA
2 NA  2 NA NA  5
```

What I wanted is, conditioning on all `length(!is.na(df$*))==1`, reduce `df` to :

```
df
   A  B  C  D  E
 1 1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: Is `colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)` useful? It doesn't do the NA check you mention, but not sure if that's a absolute must-have or not based on the sample data you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the resulting rows are equal, you can use:

```
dfNew <- do.call(data.frame, lapply(df, function(i) i[!is.na(i)]))
```

which results in

```
dfNew
A B C D E
1 1 2 3 4 5
```